# RRDTool: strange "splashes" in the database and on the graph

Tags: rrdtool, armbian

Recently I came across a strange behavior of rrdtool: if data was inserted into the database at a random time, "splashes" appear on the graph, this can be seen in the attached picture. I also noticed that the incoming data does not match the data in the database dump. Tell me what I'm doing wrong, please.

I've tried rrdtool versions 1.6.0 and 1.7.2, platform is Orange Pi One (armv7l) with Armbian Linux (kernel version:  5.4.45-sunxi). I also tested on x86 platform and it's looks to work fine.

[strange graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmBkJ.png)

RRD file was created with command:

```
$ rrdcreate /var/db/homed_sensor_7.rrd --step 10 DS:data:GAUGE:3600:U:U RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:8640
```

Data comes by MQTT at random time and is inserted to database with next command, for examle:

```
$ rrdupdate /var/db/homed_sensor_7.rrd N:24.8125
```

Input data log with timestamps and values:

```
$ cat /var/log/homed.log | grep 'Sensor 7' | grep '2020.08.11 08:1'
2020.08.11 08:10:08.667 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:10:09.616 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:10:13.400 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:10:14.348 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:10:40.324 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:10:41.269 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:10:45.894 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:10:46.856 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:10:54.293 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:10:55.215 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:10:58.032 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:10:58.972 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:11:03.592 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:11:04.518 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:11:22.266 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:11:23.204 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:11:49.320 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:11:50.264 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:12:08.986 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:12:09.906 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:12:19.224 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:12:20.159 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:12:35.085 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:12:35.999 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:13:10.514 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:13:11.453 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:13:34.626 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:13:36.513 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:13:57.952 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:13:58.896 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:14:12.028 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:14:12.982 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:14:33.386 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:14:34.341 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:14:43.482 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:14:43.711 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:14:45.597 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:14:46.534 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:15:08.645 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:15:09.751 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:15:12.852 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:15:13.317 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:18:41.772 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:18:42.712 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:19:07.107 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:19:08.058 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:19:33.253 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:19:34.194 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
2020.08.11 08:19:53.916 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.8125
2020.08.11 08:19:54.860 homed-sensor: Sensor 7 temperature 24.75
```

RRD dump at the same time:

```
$ rrdtool dump /var/db/rrd/homed_sensor_7.rrd | grep '2020-08-11 08:1'
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:00 MSK / 1597122600 --> <row><v>2.600518229e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:10 MSK / 1597122610 --> <row><v>2.480645131e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:20 MSK / 1597122620 --> <row><v>2.350490220e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:30 MSK / 1597122630 --> <row><v>2.546319293e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:40 MSK / 1597122640 --> <row><v>2.546319293e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:50 MSK / 1597122650 --> <row><v>2.480096602e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:11:00 MSK / 1597122660 --> <row><v>2.480094575e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:11:10 MSK / 1597122670 --> <row><v>2.391521916e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:11:20 MSK / 1597122680 --> <row><v>2.570375508e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:11:30 MSK / 1597122690 --> <row><v>2.305996423e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:11:40 MSK / 1597122700 --> <row><v>2.655912879e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:11:50 MSK / 1597122710 --> <row><v>2.480876661e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:12:00 MSK / 1597122720 --> <row><v>2.481034981e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:12:10 MSK / 1597122730 --> <row><v>2.480667576e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:12:20 MSK / 1597122740 --> <row><v>2.480821922e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:12:30 MSK / 1597122750 --> <row><v>2.481094399e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:12:40 MSK / 1597122760 --> <row><v>2.266941020e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:12:50 MSK / 1597122770 --> <row><v>2.552484289e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:13:00 MSK / 1597122780 --> <row><v>2.552484289e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:13:10 MSK / 1597122790 --> <row><v>2.552484289e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:13:20 MSK / 1597122800 --> <row><v>2.366359064e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:13:30 MSK / 1597122810 --> <row><v>2.595585752e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:13:40 MSK / 1597122820 --> <row><v>2.383080995e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:13:50 MSK / 1597122830 --> <row><v>2.578249258e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:14:00 MSK / 1597122840 --> <row><v>2.476898851e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:14:10 MSK / 1597122850 --> <row><v>2.485007357e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:14:20 MSK / 1597122860 --> <row><v>2.249212094e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:14:30 MSK / 1597122870 --> <row><v>2.712694797e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:14:40 MSK / 1597122880 --> <row><v>2.480676238e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:14:50 MSK / 1597122890 --> <row><v>2.397873126e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:15:00 MSK / 1597122900 --> <row><v>2.563894731e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:15:10 MSK / 1597122910 --> <row><v>2.480573101e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:15:20 MSK / 1597122920 --> <row><v>2.333396444e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:15:30 MSK / 1597122930 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:15:40 MSK / 1597122940 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:15:50 MSK / 1597122950 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:16:00 MSK / 1597122960 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:16:10 MSK / 1597122970 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:16:20 MSK / 1597122980 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:16:30 MSK / 1597122990 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:16:40 MSK / 1597123000 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:16:50 MSK / 1597123010 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:17:00 MSK / 1597123020 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:17:10 MSK / 1597123030 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:17:20 MSK / 1597123040 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:17:30 MSK / 1597123050 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:17:40 MSK / 1597123060 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:17:50 MSK / 1597123070 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:18:00 MSK / 1597123080 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:18:10 MSK / 1597123090 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:18:20 MSK / 1597123100 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:18:30 MSK / 1597123110 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:18:40 MSK / 1597123120 --> <row><v>2.488628828e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:18:50 MSK / 1597123130 --> <row><v>2.432612710e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:19:00 MSK / 1597123140 --> <row><v>2.529321738e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:19:10 MSK / 1597123150 --> <row><v>2.268383952e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:19:20 MSK / 1597123160 --> <row><v>2.587393409e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:19:30 MSK / 1597123170 --> <row><v>2.587393409e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:19:40 MSK / 1597123180 --> <row><v>2.316523793e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:19:50 MSK / 1597123190 --> <row><v>2.645360868e+01</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-11 08:10:00 MSK / 1597122600 --> <row><v>2.479729023e+01</v></row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by adding *closest* timestamp when inserting data into the database:

```
$ rrdupdate /var/db/homed_sensor_7.rrd 1597122920:24.8125
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Data Normalisation causing your issue.

In simple terms, the RRD *must* have data exactly on the configured time interval boundary.  If you provide data offset to that, then it will use a straight-line interpolation to try and estimate it, based on the available samples and their points in time.

If your sample is a long way off, this can mean it overestimates the next one, and as a result underestimates the following.  The overall average will be correct, but you'll have spikes (as you can see).

The solution, as you spotted, is to make sure the timestamp is exactly on the time boundary - in your case, multiples of 10 seconds.

There is a good explanation of the various data manipulation going on here: http://rrdtool.vandenbogaerdt.nl/process.php